# Find / Generate documentation for Gtk, Gdk, GdkPixbuf, 

Tags: python, documentation, pygobject

Where can I find proper documentation on the Python objects `Gtk`, `Gdk`,... from `gi.repository` ?
I'm stuck with using `dir()` and it's of the utmost annoyance...

To sum it up: heelp!

(NOTE: the pygtk doc is too outdated, I'm using pygobject)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't found online documentation but you can use the help command from python interactive prompt, like:

```
>>> import gi
>>> help(gi)

Help on package gi:

NAME
    gi

FILE
    /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/gtk-2.0/gi/__init__.py

DESCRIPTION
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The GTK/GDK documentation can be found here: http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/

Comment: My problem with that is that it is **way** outdated! I'm using pygobject.

Comment: By the way, do you have any link to HTML 3.2 reference documentation ?